# Not working crystal report in visual studio 2010 (64 bit operating system)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2010

I am beginner for crystal report developing in visual studio.
I develop my c#.net project with crystal reports in visual studio 2010 in 32 bit operating system machine,when i open the same project in 64 bit operating system and same visual studio 2010,crystal reports not loading properly .it appears hexa decimal values.

[image]

Comment: You have to install it https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317789/support-for-crystal-reports-for-visual-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
http://auto-download.com/download/get/pEhZmz_Lba/crforvs_13_0_17_exe.html

install and restart visual studio